# Divide two variables returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

When I divide two variables to give the variable v1, it returns NaN?  However, all of the other variables give numbers when I use document.write

```
    min = 0.001,max = 0.1,
    c1 = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(3);

    min = 0.1,max = 1000,
    kcat = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    var Eo = 0.1;
    var Vmax = (Eo*kcat);

    min = 0.1,max = 100,
    Km = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    v1t = (c1)*(Vmax);
    document.write(v1t); //GIVES NUMBER
    v1b = (c1)+(Km);
    document.write(v1b); //GIVES NUMBER

v1 = v1t / v1b;
document.write(v1); //returns NaN
```

Comment: your first `document.write()` prints `v1b` btw...

Comment: first check the variable v1b not null/zero

Comment: I changed v1b - The document.write gives me: 7.311683935222926 and 0.07472.59526266876507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toFixed` builds a string (for example `"0.013"`). When you add a number using `(c1)+(Km)`, it gives a string like this one :

```
"0.01339.069145169761036"
```

And dividing a number by a string using `v1t / v1b` gives `NaN`.

Why are you using `toFixed`? There doesn't seem to be any good reason to do so. But if you really want to use it, apply `parseFloat` to the result before using it in a computation.

Comment: Thanks this is great - I was using ToFixed because I display the c values later and didn't want them to be too long, but I will use .ToFixed just before writing it!

Comment: Use `toFixed` only when you print the value. And don't store it if you don't reuse it.

Comment: However, is it possible to round number values, that can be used as numbers?

Comment: Yes. Apart simply parsing the result of toFixed (which isn't eleguant) you can use Math.round, Math.ceil and Math.floor.

Comment: I'm looking at math.round now. Thanks!